# Regexp to match string of UPPERCASE words, separated by SINGLE spaces, length of string <= 20

Tags: regex, string, limit

Okay, here goes:
the goal is to make regexp that matches "BLABLA BLA B BLAB"-like string, something like:

```
^[A-Z](\s?[A-Z])*$
```

but the main problem is that the length of the matched string can be anything between 1 and infinity. So is it possible to make a regexp that behaves exactly like the one above, but matches only if the string length is less or equal to 20 chars? (Spaces at the beginning and/or end of the string are not allowed.)

**I understand** that in this case it is better to alter string length outside of regexp (in the code of my app for example, already done this), but I'm just curious if I'm missing something simple?

Edit: 20 characters is the full length of the string, including optional **single** spaces between words. Word length can be 1 char or more.
So, "AAAAABBBBBDDDDDEEEEE" (20 uppercase letters) should match, "AAAAABBBBB CCCCDDDDD" should match (1 space in-between), "AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDDD" should match (3 **single** spaces in-between, string length is 20), "AA B" should match (single space in-between, overall length < 20), "AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDDF" shouldn't match (because string length is 21) etc.

Comment: It's always helpful when asking regex questions to provide sample input and expected output. Do the spaces count in the 20 characters?

Comment: yes, 20 chars is the full length including spaces in-between words, so the string can be just of 20 letters, or 19 letters with one space somewhere except beginning/end etc. Sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
^(?=.{1,20}$)[A-Z](\s?[A-Z])*$
```

Comment: Damn, I knew that it's something related to lookaheads. Brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
^(?=.{1,20}$)([A-Z]+\s?)+[A-Z]$
```

Comment: Unfortunately this expression allows such unwanted things: 1) Allows spaces in the beginning and the end of string 2) allows multiple spaces between any two words - only one space between any two words should be allowed.

Comment: Excuse me if this sounds stupid (or if I misunderstood) but wasn't the entire string supposed to be max 20 characters (`[A-Z\s]`)?

Comment: Nice! Just for reference (pun intended:) , take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html. You also want to change from {1,20) to {1,19} since there is a [A-Z] mandatory at the end.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It looks that I need more knowledge in lookahead-related stuff. Great post.